# no FaceTime pure audio call (audio only)

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, apple-id, facetime

It is only possible to make or receive a Facetime video call with an iPhone 11. A pure Facetime audio call is not possible.

The latest software update is installed. Same Apple ID on iPad and iPhone.

**Iphone 11:**
Facetime video call works,
Facetime Audio only does not work (neither incoming nor outgoing)

**Ipad 9:**
Facetime audio and
Facetime video works (incoming and outgoing)

Signed in to Facetime and iMessage on both devices with the same mobile number and Apple ID.

All settings were compared with the devices of another Apple ID in the same household, where everything works as desired.

We do not understand why the iPhone 11 cannot accept or start Facetime audio calls. Facetime with video works incoming and outgoing, but it is not possible to turn off the camera during a Facetime video call because the button is grayed out.

Here is a screenshot where it is impossible to deactivate the camera: [image: FaceTime Video Call impossible to deactivate Camera]

When attempting FaceTime call, the iPhone and the iPad are ringing. When attempting a FaceTime pure audio call to the same AppleID, only the iPad is ringing.

Comment: Can help this link [https://support.apple.com/en-gb](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iphfb3d2a12b/ios#)

Comment: This solves not really the issue. Because even that way I would have to establish a video call in the first place. I would like to call the iPhone directly. When using now the FaceTime audio call, the call will only be presented at the iPad and not on the iPhone.

Comment: I just double checked, it is impossible to turn off the camera during a FaceTime call. The button is not available because it is grayed out.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot from this grayed out button to turn off the camera would be helpful

Comment: @SwissCodeMen the screenshot post has been added to the post